# Enabling proxy_arp for interface eth2.1

Tags: linux, networking, command-line, proxy-arp

Am trying to enable proxy arp for some of the interfaces, with the normal interface name eth0, eth1, etc

```
[root@eth2.1]# sysctl net.ipv4.conf.eth0.proxy_arp
0
```

But for interface names such as "eth1.11, eth2.1" its giving the below error.
Tried different format "", '' etc. but no help.

```
[root@eth2.1]# sysctl net.ipv4.conf.eth2.1.proxy_arp
error: "net.ipv4.conf.eth2\.1.proxy_arp" is an unknown key
```

can anyone please point out the correct way to do this ?

Comment: Someone more experienced than I may chime in, but my understanding is that the proxy_arp flag is only valid on the physical interface and not on the aliased ones.

Comment: its not an aliased interface, its name is eth2.1 . 
not eth2:1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found out the way to doing this, here it goes.
It seems that  is replaced by /, that made it work.

```
sysctl net.ipv4.conf.eth2/1.proxy_arp
```